# How to navigate activitie's layout through tabs android java

Tags: java, android, tabs

In my android application I have three layout's activity and three tabs and below is my activity_1:

```
package com.example.testapp;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import android.support.v4.*;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.app.TabActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Bitmap.CompressFormat;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.util.Base64;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TabHost;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class MainActivity extends TabActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        txt_display = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt_display);
        btn_s = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_go);

        TabHost tabHost = getTabHost(); 
        TabHost.TabSpec spec; 
        Intent intent_one; 

        intent_one = new Intent().setClass(this, MainActivity.class);

           spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("tabOne");  
           spec.setContent(intent_one); 
           spec.setIndicator("Tab One"); 
           tabHost.addTab(spec);   
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

below is layout of this activity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                  android:layout_width="match_parent"
                  android:layout_height="match_parent">

     <TabHost 
 android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent">
 <LinearLayout
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent">
  <TabWidget
   android:id="@android:id/tabs"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
  <FrameLayout
   android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
 </LinearLayout>
</TabHost>

<RelativeLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.testapp.MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_display"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="96dp"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

</RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I am doing the same code in the other two activities, and I want to change layout's activity through tabs and i am using `api level-16` and `v7` but getting exception

```
The type TabActivity is deprecated
```

How can I resolve this issue, kindly suggest me waiting for reply.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is done by the view pager and fragment.

[Here](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/lateral.html)

is the link to develope the swipable tabs. you'll get a demo code for that.

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation

> New applications should use Fragments instead of this class; to
>   continue to run on older devices, you can use the v4 support library
>   which provides a version of the Fragment API that is compatible down
>   to DONUT.

So use [fragments](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html) instead.